# Actionscript 3.0 - Calling a function from another class

Tags: actionscript-3

First off, yes, I am aware this question has been asked a hundred times, but after reading through a good deal of them, I couldn't figure it out.

I have two classes, Main and ActorSpawner, and I'm trying to call a method of ActorSpawner, stageSpawner, from Main.  I've tested it with the contents of the stageSpawner method in the Main class's Main method, and it worked just fine.  But when I moved it to its own class, it stopped working.  I'm not currently getting any error messages and everything seems to be typed correctly, so I have absolutely no idea what the problem is.

**Main**

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public var spawnerMain:ActorSpawner;

    public function Main() {
        spawnerMain = new ActorSpawner();
        spawnerMain.stageSpawner();

    }
}
```

}

**ActorSpawner**

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class ActorSpawner extends MovieClip {

    public var background:Background;
    public var barrel:Barrel;
    public var turret:Turret;

    public function stageSpawner() {

        background = new Background();
        addChild(background);
        setChildIndex(background, 0);

        barrel = new Barrel();
        addChild(barrel);
        setChildIndex(barrel, 1);

        turret = new Turret();
        addChild(turret);
        setChildIndex(turret, 2);
    }
}
```

}

Help?

Comment: If the question is "I don't see the objets I instantiated", the ActorSpawner is adding the elements to his children list. Shouldn't you add the ACtorSpawner as a child of the Main MovieClip ? (my Flash is a little rusty, my apologize)

Comment: That did it!  I simply added "addChild(spawnerMain);" between "spawnerMain = new ActorSpawner();" and "spawnerMain.stageSpawner();" and my objects appeared on the stage.

Thanks for the help!